# P256 creation under ios 10 - 12

Tags: swift, cryptography

Is there is any way to create private key of type P256 under ios 10-13 with apple native libraries?
CryptoKit is available only from ios13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating such key is possible with the next code

```swift
func createPrivateKey() {
    let attributes = [
        kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
        kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: 256,
        kSecAttrIsPermanent: false
    ] as [CFString: Any]
    
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    let privateKey = SecKeyCreateRandomKey(attributes as CFDictionary, &error)
    print(privateKey ?? error!.takeUnretainedValue())
}
```

Bytes from this SecKey are valid to recreate with them P256 key with function

```swift
try P256.Signing.PrivateKey(rawRepresentation: "PRIVATE_KEY_DATA")
```